# Creating 2 numbers from a one #C

Tags: c#

I should create two new numbers from a one, the first group will contain digits which are divisible by 2 and the other group will contain the others.

```
int checkCount = 94321, num1 = 94321, count2 = 0, countRest = 0;

        while (checkCount > 0)
        {   
            if (checkCount % 2 == 0)
                count2++;
            else
                countRest++;
            checkCount /= 10;
        }

        int[] a = new int[count2];
        int[] b = new int[countRest];

        int k2 = 0, kRest = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < a.Length + b.Length; j++) 
        {
            if (num1 % 2 == 0)
            {
                a[k2] = num1 % 10;
                k2++;
            }
            else
            {
                b[kRest] = num1 % 10;
                kRest++;
            }
            num1 /= 10;
        }
```

I created two arrays with the numbers I should use, now how can I build two INT varabile when each one contains all of the numbers together from the array?

Example:
If I have this number - 12345 so
var = 24, other var = 135

If you have another solution without arrays I think it will be better.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you post 2 more example so we can see what pattern there is?

Comment: Are you trying to construct a single number string by taking alternating characters from two different number strings?

Comment: @sergio - from 629831 you will get 628 and 931, from 91822 you get 91 and 822. @tobias - it shouldn't be a string.. it should be two int variables.

Comment: @Luis: I still don't see a pattern, it seems you're grabbing numbers at random. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Sergio - odds & evens, left to right...

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This splits number 12345 to numbers 135 and 24.

```
int checkCount = 12345;
int even = 0;
int odd = 0;
int reverseEven = 0;
int reverseOdd = 0;

while (checkCount > 0) {
    int current = checkCount % 10;
    if (current % 2 == 0) {
        reverseEven = 10 * reverseEven + current;
    } else {
        reverseOdd = 10 * reverseOdd + current;
    }

    checkCount /= 10;
}


while (reverseEven > 0) {
    even = 10 * even + reverseEven % 10;
    reverseEven /= 10;
}

while (reverseOdd > 0) {
    odd = 10 * odd + reverseOdd % 10;
    reverseOdd /= 10;
}

Console.WriteLine("even: {0}", even);
Console.WriteLine("odd: {0}", odd);
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just:

```
    int decimalMaskA = 1;
    int decimalMaskB = 1;
    while (checkCount > 0)
    {   
        if (checkCount % 2 == 0)
        {
            count2 = count2 + (checkCount % 10)*decimalMaskA;
            decimalMaskA *= 10;
        }
        else
        {
            countRest = countRest + (checkCount % 10)*decimalMaskB;
            decimalMaskB *= 10;
        }
        checkCount /= 10;
    }
```

`count2` and `countRest` will contain those numbers (135 and 24) instead of counts.

Comment: They will contain the numbers 531 and 42.

Comment: Nice way, but you get it from right to left ;) I need 42 and 531 (if the number is 54321

Comment: @Andrey: Now you have 13500 and 2040. Your current approach needs two masks (and one bugfix) if you want to get it right. Still, I prefer my own answer ;)

Comment: I tried with two masks but it still doesn't work. thank you very much but the mgronber's answer is fine. :)

Comment: @Luis it is fine but contains 3 loops instead of one. btw I fixed mine.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I build two INT varabile
>   when each one contains all of the
>   numbers together from the array?

I can't say for sure, but I *think* you're asking how to assemble a number given each of its digits in decreasing order of significance.

To 'append' a digit to a number, you can multiply the number by 10 and then add the digit to that. To create the 'assembled' number, you can perform this operation for each digit in the array,

```
int[] digits = ...
int num = digits.Aggregate(0, (numSoFar, digit) => 10 * numSoFar + digit);
```

As a loop, this would look like:

```
int num = 0;

foreach(int digit in digits)
{
    num = 10 * num + digit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're looking for this will do the trick:

```
        //Setup a sample array
        int[] a = new int[2];
        a[0] = 2;
        a[1] = 4;

        //Convert each item to a string, convert that to a string array, join the strings and turn into an int
        int output = int.Parse(String.Join("", a.Select(s => s.ToString()).ToArray()));
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
int number = 12345;

string result1 = "";
string result2 = "";

string numberString = number.ToString();

for (int i = 0; i < numberString.Length; i++ )
{
    if (numberString[i] % 2 == 0)
    {
        result1 = result1 + numberString[i];
    }
    else
    {
        result2 = result2 + numberString[i];
    }
}

int evenNumbers = int.Parse(result1);
int oddNumbers = int.Parse(result2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be...

```
var num1 = 94321;
var oddFinal = 0;
var evenFinal = 0;

var odd = new List<int>();
var even = new List<int>();

while( num1>0 )
{
    if( num1 % 2 == 0 )
        odd.Add( num1 % 10 );
    else
        even.Add( num1 % 10 );

    num1 = num1 / 10;
}    

for (int i = 0; i < odd.Count; i++)
{
    oddFinal += odd[i] * (int) Math.Pow(10,i);
}

for (int i = 0; i < even.Count; i++)
{
    evenFinal += even[i] * (int) Math.Pow(10,i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with LINQ,

```
int num = 92345;
            string strNum = Convert.ToString(num);

            var divisibleby2 = from c in strNum
                               where int.Parse(c.ToString()) % 2 == 0
                               select c.ToString();

            var notDivisibleby2 = from c in strNum
                               where int.Parse(c.ToString()) % 2 != 0
                                  select c.ToString();

            int int_divisibleby2num = int.Parse(String.Join("", divisibleby2.ToArray()));
            int int_Notdivisibleby2num = int.Parse(String.Join("", notDivisibleby2.ToArray()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Every programmer should write wacky code at least once a day:

```
        int checkCount = 12345, numEven, numOdd;
        Boolean result;

        result = int.TryParse(checkCount.ToString().Replace("0", "").Replace("2", "").Replace("4", "").Replace("6", "").Replace("8", ""), out numOdd);
        result = int.TryParse(checkCount.ToString().Replace("1", "").Replace("3", "").Replace("5", "").Replace("7", "").Replace("9", ""), out numEven);
```